# SQL query: combining data from two tables

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two tables: `USERS` and `USER_TOKENS`

`USERS` is structured as follows:

```
id (INT)
name (VARCHAR)
pass (VARCHAR)
birthdate (DATETIME)
...
etc
```

`USER_TOKENS` is structured as follows:

```
user_id (INT)
key     (VARCHAR) 
value   (VARCHAR)
```

Essentially `USERS` contains basic data, whereas `USER_TOKENS` is used to store completely arbitrary KEY/VALUE pairs for a given user. So for example there may be 3 records for the USER whose id is 137:

```
user_id:137;   key:"height";    value:"610";
user_id:137;   key:"food";      value:"candy";
user_id:137;   key:"income";    value:"low";
```

Now, to the point:
How do I query the DB to get all the records from table `USER` where `USER.name = 'bob'`, but at the same time ALL the records from `USER_TOKENS` for each one of the selected users?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you need really all matching users and their respective tokens as one resultset, you can try this:

```
SELECT u.id, ut.key, ut.value  -- and list also other required fields
FROM Users u 
LEFT JOIN User_tokens ut ON u.id = ut.user_id 
WHERE u.name = 'bob'
```

Try not to use `SELECT *` because you get duplicate fields that way (you get both `users.id` and `user_tokens.user_id` which are allways equal). Using LEFT JOIN you also get users that do not have any tokens.

But this query does not make sense to me very much, because you allready know the user, so why to repeat the users' data in every single row. (It would only make sense if there would be more users with the name of 'bob').

You probably need something like this:

```
SELECT ut.key, ut.value  
FROM Users u 
INNER JOIN User_tokens ut ON u.id = ut.user_id 
WHERE u.name = 'bob'
```

Or perhaps better:

```
SELECT ut.key, ut.value  
FROM User_tokens ut 
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT * FROM Users u WHERE u.name = 'bob' AND u.id = ut.user_id)
```

This lists all the tokens for all the users with name='bob'.

If there is only one `bob` then there is no need to include all the duplicate data from `users` table - you can get them eventually with a separate SELECT that would return one single row.

Comment: +1 for being the first person to walk through and explain it and not just copy and paste code.

Comment: Thanks, thoroughly explained, and of course working. However, concerning the last code snippet, I will never be in a scenario where I address a specific user, otherwise as you said I could just  get it done with two separate queries. It's more like there could be 100 "bob" users, or I should gather all the users whose name is like "b%"

Comment: An issue with the above. Given that "NAME" is used as a field name in both the table, the final result bears ambiguities when being fetched through a php PDO using FETCH_ASSOC. Any way to get the columns outputted with the full TABLE.COLUMN format?

Comment: Just use `SELECT u.name AS user_name, ut.name AS token_name ... FROM Users u ...`.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT u.*, t.* FROM users AS u, users_tokens AS t 
WHERE u.name = 'bob' AND t.user_id = u.id;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * 
FROM USER 
INNER JOIN USER_RECORDS ON USER.id = USER_RECORDS.user_id 
WHERE user.name = 'bob'
```